# How to avoid validation loop?

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form that has two checkboxes, "A" and "B" and the form that is broken into steps. If "A" is checked and "B" isn't I need to display an alert when user clicks on the next step button, stopping the form from progressing  only once,. like

```
if ($("#A").is(":checked") && $("B").is(":not("checked")") {
  alert("foo");
});
```

how do I make this happen only once, that is display the alert, user clicks "OK" to close alert and is allowed to progress on through the form?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should be like this:

```
if ($("#A").is(":checked") && $("B").is(":not(':checked')") {
 alert("foo");
});
```

**Update:**

Use the jQuery's [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) handler.

Comment: Sorry about the syntax error, but back to the question, how do I get it to happen when user hits the next step button ("#step0Next") and only happen the first time they click on it?


$("#step0Next").click(function() {
 if ($("A").is(":checked") && $("B").is(":not(':checked')") {
 //alert her but only once
}
});

Comment: is there something I'm missing? #step0Next is the button ID, 
  $("#step0Next").one('click', function() {
   if($("#A").is(":checked") && $("#B").is(":not(:checked)")) {
   alert("foo");
  }
 });

doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
var userHasBeenAlerted = false;
if ($("#A").is(":checked") && $("B").is(":not(':checked')" && !userHasBeenAlerted) {
 userHasBeenAlerted = true;
 alert("foo");
});
```

Although I don't really follow what you mean with 'broken into steps', page reloads etc? If that is the case set it in a more global way (like a cookie or something)